# Function placement, Shape Error, and Executing code when a formula changes a cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

ok so I have burned more of a day reading on this and going around in circles.

### SITUATION

On a worksheet called "Analysis" in Cells N279:O279 I have named the range CL1_W_F

On a worksheet called "Analysis" in Cells N280:O280 I have named the range CL2_W_F

On a worksheet called "Analysis" in Cells N281:O281 I have named the range CL3_W_F

The numbers in those cells are a results from a formula

On a worksheet called "posting" in cell J30 I have the formula "Min(CL1_W_F)"

On worksheet called "Posting" I have 1 picture and 3 text boxes.  I was able to rename them and manipulate them using shapes("Triple Posting Sign") for the picture and shapes("Single Truck Load"), shapes("Truck and Trailer Load") or shapes("Truck Train Load")

### OBJECTIVE

What I am trying to achieve is to turn the visibility of the 4 shapes to True when the value in J30 is less than 1 and Greater than or equal to 0.3.  When the value is outside the test values, then the visibility should be set to False.

### What I have tried

I read a bunch of different options for monitoring the cell J30 changing since its due to a formula, but I got lost and confused in that process.  Then I read something about embedding the changes you want to happen into a FUNCTION call and that sounded simple enough so I tried the following

```
Function Capacity_Factor_Fetch2() As Long

Dim Status As Boolean
Dim Da_Range As Range

Set Da_Range = Sheets("Analysis").Range("CL1_W_F")

Status = False

If Sheets("POSTING").Range("j30").Value < 1 And Sheets("POSTING").Range("j30").Value >= 0.3 Then
    Status = True
End If

Shapes("Single Truck Load").Visible = Status
Shapes("Truck and Trailer Load").Visible = Status
Shapes("Truck Train Load").Visible = Status
Shapes("Triple Posting Sign").Visible = Status

Capacity_Factor_Fetch2 = WorksheetFunction.Min(Da_Range)

End Function
```

The problem I encountered is I originally placed it in sheet6(POSTING) and could not call the function when I tried entering "=Capacity_Factor_Fetch2" in cell J30.  I could however step through it using "F8" and it did what I wanted it to.  I then copied and pasted the code into "Module1".  This allowed me to call it from the worksheet but I now get Compile error: Sub or Function not defined.  When I click ok to clear the error window the word "Shapes" is highlighted on the first line of changing the visibility status.

So I am now stuck with either not being able to call code that works, or being able to call code that won't compile.

Any assistance with A) why I am having the errors and how to fix them, B) a more elegant solution that may require spoon feeding me.

Comment: I also tried a variation where I passed CL1_W_F as a range to the function:  `Function Capacity_Factor_Fetch2(Da_Range as Range) As Long`.  However when I did this I could no longer step through the code and ultimately it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UDF (User Defined Function) should only return a value. It should not do anything else. Especially it can't changing cell values in the same manner a `Sub` will can. The error will disappear if you would use fully qualified references for the shapes `Sheets("POSTING").Shapes("Single Truck Load")` but then the next error will appear, that is the kind of circular reference since you trying to to get the value from `J30` which is the cell in which the formula resides which calls the function.

You could have a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` in the sheet "Analysis" which will react if something in the named range `CL1_W_F` has changed.

Like so:

Code in the worksheet class module "Analysis":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 On Error GoTo mEnd
 If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("CL1_W_F")) Is Nothing Then

  Status = False

  If Sheets("POSTING").Range("J30").Value < 1 And Sheets("POSTING").Range("J30").Value >= 0.3 Then
    Status = True
  End If

  Sheets("POSTING").Shapes("Single Truck Load").Visible = Status

 End If
mEnd:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This approach will only work if the values in in the named range `CL1_W_F` are changed directly since the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` is not involved if the values change because of changes on other cells. If the values in in the named range `CL1_W_F` are changed directly, it will be the best approach in my opinion.

With the following code your approach will also work but only as a volatile function. This is not my recommendation but will be necessary  if the values in in the named range `CL1_W_F` are not changed directly.

The code in a `Module` and used as Formula `=Capacity_Factor_Fetch2()`

```
Public Function Capacity_Factor_Fetch2() As Double

 Application.Volatile
 Dim Status As Boolean
 Dim Da_Range As Range
 Dim dMin As Double

 Set Da_Range = Sheets("Analysis").Range("CL1_W_F")

 dMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(Da_Range)

 Status = False

 If dMin < 1 And dMin >= 0.3 Then
    Status = True
 End If

 Sheets("POSTING").Shapes("Single Truck Load").Visible = Status
 'Sheets("POSTING").Shapes("Truck and Trailer Load").Visible = Status
 'Sheets("POSTING").Shapes("Truck Train Load").Visible = Status
 'Sheets("POSTING").Shapes("Triple Posting Sign").Visible = Status

 Capacity_Factor_Fetch2 = dMin

End Function
```

As of the comment from Rory you could also have a `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` in the sheet "Posting" like so:

Code in the worksheet class module "Posting":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

  Status = False

  If Me.Range("J30").Value < 1 And Me.Range("J30").Value >= 0.3 Then
    Status = True
  End If

  Me.Shapes("Single Truck Load").Visible = Status


End Sub
```

`Me` here stands for the worksheet "Posting" since this code resides in the class module of this worksheet. `Me` is a default reference in class modules like `this` in some other languages.

That will really be the best approach, thanks to Rory.

Comment: You could also use `Worksheet_Calculate` since the inputs are formulas.

Comment: @Rory: Thanks for the hint. That will be the best approach.

Comment: 2 questions:  1) Does UDF stand for USER DEFINED FUNCTION?  I have seen it more than a few times and I have been guessing at its definition.  2)  In the last block of code for Worksheet_Calculate you have Me.range and Me.Shapes.  Is Me fine as is or is there also supposed to be a `dim me as worksheet` and `set Me = sheets("POSTING").  Thanks for the informative and detailed response.  CL1_W_F is populated with formulas so no user entry is occurring there.  As an option I could go further up the food chain and monitor every single data entry point over 5 worksheets but that seemed cumbersome.

Comment: See my supplement. So the last approach should work for you.

Comment: it works...as an unintended side effect, I can no longer perform an undo.  I will have to do some more testing to see if it is actually due to the code implementation.

Comment: Further testing shows my workbook had been corrupted somehow and that after restarting excel I can now undo again.

Comment: Yes, `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` clears the undo chain. If this is not acceptable for you, you must use the UDF approach.